# Creating a counter that updates every 30 seconds for checking windows service status

Tags: powershell

I need to update a counter every 30 seconds to check windows update service status to running.

The below code snippet just updates counter for checking windows update service status as "running". But how to make counter update itself after waiting timeout of 30 seconds?

```
$services = "wuauserv"
$counter = 8
$status = "Running" 
do 
{
    $count = (Get-Service $services | ? {$_.status -eq $status}).count
    $counter--
} until ($count -eq 0 -or $counter -eq 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a sleep command inside your loop:

```
Start-Sleep -Seconds 30
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a real timer :

```
$timer = New-Object -Type Timers.Timer
$timer.Interval  = 3000 #3 seconds

$job = Register-ObjectEvent -InputObject $Timer  -EventName Elapsed  -SourceIdentifier TimerEvent  -Action {Write-Host "[$(Get-Date)] Coucou!" } -MaxTriggerCount 5 

# Start the timer
$timer.Start()

# Stop your code
Wait-Job $job -Timeout 16

#Stop the timer
$timer.Stop()


# When You completely finished with this, you have to cleanup by unregistering the event handler and remove the PSJob.
Get-EventSubscriber | Unregister-Event
Get-Job | Remove-Job
```

The `-MaxTriggerCount 5` is the équivalent to your `$counter`.

The Wait-Job $job -Timeout 16 in case you do not want to do anything else in the elapsed time.

When You completely finished with this, you have to cleanup by unregistering the event handler and remove the PSJob.

```
Get-EventSubscriber | Unregister-Event
Get-Job | Remove-Job
```